# how to set state on onChangeText for inner object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do use onChangeMyData method, the one below doesn't set the state.
    How can i assign state for user object by passing the Key.
    If it is a nested object.Thanks in advance

```
<TextInput 
   value={user ? user.FirstName : ''}
   onChangeText={text =>
   this.onChangeMyData('FirstName', text)}

<TextInput 
   value={user ? user.LastName : ''}
   onChangeText={text =>
   this.onChangeMyData('LastName', text)}/>

<TextInput 
    value={toGoData ? toGoData.Note : ''}
    onChangeText={text =>
    this.onChangeMyData('Note', text)} />

 private onChangeMyData(key: keyof IData, value: any) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            myData: { ...prevState.myData, [key]: value },
        }));
   }

interface IData{
  user:Person,
  Note:string
 }

interface Person {
 FirstName:string,
 LastName:string
 }
```

Comment: This is not complete code, but did you bind your function (onChangeMyData)?

Comment: try this one first: 
 private onChangeMyData = (key: keyof IData, value: any) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            myData: { ...prevState.myData, [key]: value },
        }));
   }

Comment: @m.akbari
I have mention this i my code.
 private onChangeMyData(key: keyof IData, value: any) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            myData: { ...prevState.myData, [key]: value },
        }));
   }

Comment: I doest get set to user, because use is nested object

Comment: OK, but the comment I wrote is different, it is with arrow function. The main question is "Did you bind your onChangeMyData Function in constructor? "

Comment: yes i Have used 
this.onChangeMyData= this.onChangeMyData.bind(this)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this example, the default values are in the state, and the onChange function changes the state to the name of the field where it is triggered.

```
import React from 'react';
class UseLegalyonChange extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            lastname:"",
            phone:"",
            address:"",
            firstname:""
        }
        this.handleonChange=this.handleonChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleonChange(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.firstname}  name="firstname"  onChange={(e)=>this.handleonChange(e)}/>  
                <input type="text" value={this.state.lastname} name="lastname"  onChange={(e)=>this.handleonChange(e)}/>  
                <input type="text" value={this.state.address}  name="address" onChange={(e)=>this.handleonChange(e)}/>  
                <input type="text" value={this.state.phone}  name="phone" onChange={(e)=>this.handleonChange(e)}/>  
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default UseLegalyonChange
```

Comment: How will you set if the state is like
this.state={
            lastname:"",
            phone:"",
            address:"",
            firstname:""
           hobby:{
hobbyID:'',:
hobbyName        }

How will set hobby here?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put hobbyID and  hobbyName at the same level as firstname and then rebuild your json when submitting the form. Otherwise it will rewrite the function handleonChange  in another way

Comment: thanks for your comment. But we need to update a State which are having nested object.